# Beautiful Soup returns 'none'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using the following code to extract data using beautiful soup:

```
import requests
import bs4
res = requests.get('https://www.jmu.edu/cgi-bin/parking_sign_data.cgi?hash=53616c7465645f5f5c0bbd0eccccb6fe8dd7ed9a0445247e3c7dcb4f91927f7ccc933be780c6e558afb8ebf73620c3e5e3b2c68cd3c138519068eac99d9bf30e1e67ce894deb3a054f95f882da2ea2f0|869835tg89dhkdnbnsv5sg5wg0vmcf4mfcfc2qwm5968unmeh5')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'xml')
soup.find_all("span", class_="text")
```

I've tried different variations of the last line trying to get the program to display anything at all but each time it returns "None" or an empty list. The only thing i can get to display is the entire html of the site using: `print(soup.contents)`. The data I am trying to extract is the "Display" tag value within each of the signID tags. The data is clearly there when it prints the entire HTML of the site.

Additional Information: The the number I am trying to extract is the current number of spaces in a parking deck, so the website is updated by the second.

Additional Information 2: This site is an iframe of https://www.jmu.edu/parking/. The data I am after is in the bottom right corner under "commuter parking"

Website URL: https://www.jmu.edu/cgi-bin/parking_sign_data.cgi?hash=53616c7465645f5f5c0bbd0eccccb6fe8dd7ed9a0445247e3c7dcb4f91927f7ccc933be780c6e558afb8ebf73620c3e5e3b2c68cd3c138519068eac99d9bf30e1e67ce894deb3a054f95f882da2ea2f0|869835tg89dhkdnbnsv5sg5wg0vmcf4mfcfc2qwm5968unmeh5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you're trying to extract `Display` tag values under each `Sign` tags. Hope this helps for you.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res = requests.get('https://www.jmu.edu/cgi-bin/parking_sign_data.cgi?hash=53616c7465645f5f5c0bbd0eccccb6fe8dd7ed9a0445247e3c7dcb4f91927f7ccc933be780c6e558afb8ebf73620c3e5e3b2c68cd3c138519068eac99d9bf30e1e67ce894deb3a054f95f882da2ea2f0|869835tg89dhkdnbnsv5sg5wg0vmcf4mfcfc2qwm5968unmeh5')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
for data in soup.find_all('sign'):
    print(data.signid.text, data.display.text)
```

Output:

```
1  442
2  442
3  442
4 Happy Holidays
5 Happy Holidays
```

I have showed output for 5 values only and this gives 57 `signId` and `Display` values.

You can directly use `soup.find_all('display')` if you want only `Display` values. I have used `signId` and `Display` in the example just for reference.